# Selecting non duplicate columns in Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to look in the Email Address list where there are duplicates

There is a possibility too that the LoginName is identical except a 1 after it. eg. `Tom`, `Tom1`, and the CreatedDate is close (Under a minute)

I'm not sure if the CreateDate is fully required, but so far I can get a list of emails with duplicate - which I then use as a where clause for the email:

```
SELECT * 
FROM WWW_Login nolock
WHERE EmailAddress IN (
                        SELECT EmailAddress FROM WWW_Login
                        GROUP BY EmailAddress
                        HAVING COUNT(EmailAddress) >1 )
    AND CreatedDate >= DATEADD(dd,-10,GETDATE())
ORDER BY LoginName asc
```

What I would like from this is to only have a list of those account where the LoginName is like itself XOR itself+1

For example:

```
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| LoginName    | EmailAddress     | CreatedDate      |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| Tom          | tom@email.com    | 28/10/2022 13:00 |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| Tom1         | tom@email.com    | 28/10/2022 13:01 |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| Chris        | chris@email.com  | 25/10/2022 13:00 |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| Chris1       | chris@email.com  | 25/10/2022 13:01 |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| Post.Malone  | postie@email.com | 27/10/2022 12:14 |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| Post.Malone1 | postie@email.com | 27/10/2022 12:15 |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Unfortunately at the moment, I can't get the LoginName to order "at the same time" as email address.

If I order by LoginName, I can get a large group of similar names, but different emails

If I order by EmailAddres, I just get a list of users with two accounts under one email, with the odd smattering of "true" duplicates I'm looking for

Neither are like the above table

Comment: Pleae actually include both sample starting data and the results you want, in your question. Please don't use images of data, we should be able to copy and paste your data for testing and/or demos of our answers working. I recommend reading this SO article ; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Please note that using `NOLOCK` is a very bad thing to do unless you are in a specific logic where you realy want to skip locks (that I'm sure you don't want to do here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```
WITH TMP (LoginName, EmailAddress, CreatedDate) AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES
            ('Tom', 'tom@email.com', CONVERT(DATETIME,'2022-10-28 13:00')),
            ('Tom1', 'tom@email.com', CONVERT(DATETIME,'2022-10-28 13:00')),
            ('Tomas', 'tomas@email.com', CONVERT(DATETIME,'2022-10-28 13:00')),
            ('Tomas1', 'tomas@email.com', CONVERT(DATETIME,'2022-10-28 13:00')),
            ('Tomy', 'tomy@email.com', CONVERT(DATETIME,'2022-10-28 13:00')),
            ('Tomson', 'tomson@email.com', CONVERT(DATETIME,'2022-10-28 13:00')),
            ('Tomson2', 'tomyson@email.com', CONVERT(DATETIME,'2022-10-28 13:00'))
    )t(LoginName, EmailAddress, CreatedDate)
)

SELECT TMP1.LoginName, TMP1.EmailAddress, TMP1.CreatedDate
FROM TMP AS TMP1
INNER JOIN TMP AS TMP2 ON TMP1.EmailAddress = TMP2.EmailAddress AND (TMP1.LoginName + '1' = TMP2.LoginName OR TMP1.LoginName = TMP2.LoginName + '1')
ORDER BY TMP1.EmailAddress, TMP1.LoginName ASC
```

from :

```
| LoginName     | EmailAddress          | CreatedDate               |
|-----------    |-------------------    |-------------------------  |
| Tom           | tom@email.com         | 2022-10-28 13:00:00.000   |
| Tom1          | tom@email.com         | 2022-10-28 13:00:00.000   |
| Tomas1        | tomas@email.com       | 2022-10-28 13:00:00.000   |
| Tomas         | tomas@email.com       | 2022-10-28 13:00:00.000   |
| Tomy          | tomy@email.com        | 2022-10-28 13:00:00.000   |
| Tomson        | tomson@email.com      | 2022-10-28 13:00:00.000   |
| Tomson2       | tomyson@email.com     | 2022-10-28 13:00:00.000   |
```

result :

```
| LoginName     | EmailAddress      | CreatedDate               |
|-----------    |-----------------  |-------------------------  |
| Tom           | tom@email.com     | 2022-10-28 13:00:00.000   |
| Tom1          | tom@email.com     | 2022-10-28 13:00:00.000   |
| Tomas         | tomas@email.com   | 2022-10-28 13:00:00.000   |
| Tomas1        | tomas@email.com   | 2022-10-28 13:00:00.000   |
```

Comment: This is great. I've also added `AND (DATEDIFF(minute,TMP1.CreatedDate,TMP2.CreatedDate) <= 5)` but it's now giving me some values where there's only 1 email address, would you know how to eliminate these?

Comment: Yup, `DATEDIFF` returns an `INT` and `DATEDIFF(minute,A,B) = - DATEDIFF(minute,B,A)`. It returns you a row since `6 !< 5` but `-6 < 5`. So you need to use the `ABS` function like so : `ABS(DATEDIFF(minute,TMP1.CreatedDate,TMP2.CreatedDate)) <= 5`